# Filter output of command in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

How do I print out just the hashsum and file name with sha256sum  command? I want Hashsum and just the filename instead of the full path.

Command:

```
sha256sum /mydir/someOtherDir/file.txt
```

Output:

```
123Hashsum /mydir/someOtherDir/file.txt
```

Desired Output:

```
123Hashsum file.txt
```

Comment: The easiest way to get your expected result might be to use `cd /mydir/someOtherDir/; sha256sum file.txt` instead of `sha256sum /mydir/someOtherDir/file.txt`

Comment: There are ways to do this, for instance by changing the working directory or post-processing `sha256sum`'s output. However, you may want to explain why you want to do this. If you want to use an aliased version of the command for better readability that's fine. But if you want to parse your expected output it wouldn't make sense to post-process the original output just so that you parse it a second time after that. Also: Do you need support for multiple files in different directories, for instance `sha256sum /dir1/file1 /dir2/dir3/file2`?

Comment: I was testing some C code to get hashsums of files. I know it's better to use C libraries like openssl, but this was just a small hack for a workaround using a system call. The files coming in aren't necessarily in the corresponding folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the output into variables

```
read -r sha file < <(sha256sum /mydir/someOtherDir/file.txt)
```

Then you can read just the filename with `basename`

```
echo "$sha" "$(basename "$file")"
```

Comment: or `echo "$sha ${file##*/}"` in `bash`, but not `sh`

Answer (score 0):

You can try piping to sed as below (works with absolute paths only) :

```
sha256sum /mydir/someOtherDir/file.txt | sed 's:/.*/::'
```